# Not receiving GCM push notification when VPN is connected in my Android Phone

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, openvpn

I am developing an android application & have implemented the **GCM push notifications**.Everything is working fine.I am sharing the internet connection of my PC in my android phone.I have a proxified net so either I have to connect VPN in my PC & then share that connection in the hot spot or I can share the normal connection & then connect VPN in my android phone.In the first case I'm able to receive the push notifications but in second case I'm not able to receive the push notifications.All other applications works fine in both the case like Whatsapp, Facebook etc.Why its not working for my application?
Everyone in my college uses the second method & I want them to be able to use my application.
Help please?

Answer (score 3):

Through process of elimination.

I have managed to get Join by joaoapps, which uses GCM pushes, to work with one small trick.

Use a VPN app with app filter capability (Such as VPN Client Pro, which is what I tested it on, but OpenVPN for Android might work too) to stop Google Player Services (com.google.com.android.gms) being tunneled through VPN connection (not necessarily need to filter your app).

I haven't had any problem sending/receiving pushes afterwards.

Good luck!

Comment: Please read the question carefully. I am using VPN to get internet access .So if I apply filter for google play services, then it won't have access to internet.So no push notifications.

Comment: The app filtering isn't blocking. It just routes the app along with google play services to your regular internet connection gateway, rather than using the VPN connection. The evidence suggests that the Google play services traffic isn't routed through VPN connections correctly.

Comment: Google play service and your app traffic are not treated as tethering traffic as they are legitimately mobile device generated traffic. You can still hide your desktop traffic behind your regular VPN connection just fine.